# What is \usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts} for?

Tags: packages

What is `\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}` for?
Is there a list of packages and their meaning?

Comment: On CTAN, there are many packages. You can browse by topic or subject, and read the description and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `classicReIm` by any means?

In that case this is a **Math typesetting options**, see page 7 of the Documentation;

[image]

https://ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts?lang=de

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complete TeX Live installation including the documentation, you can use `texdoc <pkg>` on your command line to get the documentation of `<pkg>`. An alternative which does essentially the same would be [texdoc.net](https://texdoc.net/).

Most LaTeX packages are listed on [CTAN](https://ctan.org) (as noted by [@Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570271/what-is-usepackageclassicreimkpfonts-for#comment1437206_570271)) where you can also search for packages. That's the place where the big LaTeX distributions get their packages from as well.

In this case the `kpfonts` package is a package which loads the Johannes Kepler fonts. It is known to be a font package with a very good support for different series and shape combinations and a large number of mathematical symbols.

And as [@Louis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570272/117050) already explained the option `classicReIm` is an option which affects the math support of the `kpfonts` package, in this case the two commands `\Re` and `\Im`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you will not find out by looking for the `kpfonts` documentation is that there is a more modern replacement that works in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, [`kpfonts-otf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts-otf/doc/Kpfonts-OTF-Doc-English.pdf).